# How to find the true height of a QWidget inside a layout with Qt expanding policy?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

My Qt program has a window, and inside the window, there is a `QVBoxLayout` layout. I added a `QLabel` to the layout with the `Qt::Expanding` size policy. here is the code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget* window = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* main_layout = new QVBoxLayout(window);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel();
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");
    label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    main_layout->addWidget(label);
    window->resize(700, 700);
    qDebug() << "height = " << label->height() << " width = " << label->width();
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I want to have the true size QLabel in the window, so I can calculate a font size for it. but when I try to get the size with `QLabel::height()`, it always gives me the same number no matter what the window size is. for example, when the window size is `(700, 700)` it gives `height =  480  width =  640`. when I set the window size to `(1000, 1000)` it prints the same. how can I get the true value of the `QLabel`?

I also tested sizeHint, which acted like `height()`.

Comment: You most call those functions after `QWidget::paintEvent()`.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani, to be complete, after `QWidget::resizeEvent` is good enough, which happens before `QWidget::paintEvent`.

Comment: @m7913d, I don't know exactly why, but I had some issues with relying on `QWidget::resizeEvent` for updating the widget size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`QWidget::resize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) doesn't resize your widget immediately if the widget is hidden:

> If the widget is visible when it is being resized, it receives a
> resize event (resizeEvent()) immediately. If the widget is not
> currently visible, it is guaranteed to receive an event before it is
> shown.

So, when the widget is still hidden, `QLabel::height()` still returns its initial value, i.e. `QLabel::sizeHint()`.

Checking `QLabel::height()` after calling `window->show()` should resolve your issue:

```
...
window->show();
qDebug() << "height = " << label->height() << " width = " << label->width();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own widget inherited from `QWiget`, and reimplements `QWidget`'s  function `showEvent(QShowEvent*)` and `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)`，and you can get true label's height in these function.